# jQuery - counting elements while saving resources

Tags: jquery, counting

I'd like to count all `.some-class` elements in my dom. but, i don't want it to be kept as a collection (it will be done many times and i only need the number).

is there another way, instead of `$(".some-class").length` or `$(".some-class").size()` ?

Comment: `$(".some-class").length` is exactly what you need, `documet.querySelectorAll('.some-class').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...i don't want it to be kept as a collection (it will be done many times and i only need the number).

That's fine, just grab the length and release the collection:

```
var count = $(".some-class").length;
```

Only the length (in `count`) will be retained, not the collection.